# $\sum \frac{a_k}{p^k}$ converges to a real number in $[0,1]$

Tags: calculus, real-analysis, sequences-and-series

Given $p \geq 2$, 
$$ \sum_{k=1}^{\infty} {\frac{a_k}{p^k}} , a_k \in \{0,1,...,p-1\}$$

converges to a real number in $[0,1]$

I was thinking maybe using geometric series the above series can written as $(p-1) \sum{a_k} $. But then again, how can we show this series actually belong to $[0,1]$ ? thanks

Comment: For convergence, use the fact that the partial sums are a non-decreasing bounded sequence. Non-decreasing is obvious, and anuy partial sum is $\lt p-1\sum_1^\infty \frac{1}{p^k}=1$ (geometric series).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Note that $a_k\leq p-1$ for each $k$. Thus...? Relate this to $$\left( {p - 1} \right)\sum\limits_{k \leqslant N} {{{\left( {{p^{ - 1}}} \right)}^k}} =\sum\limits_{k \leqslant N} {{{\left( {{p^{ - 1}}} \right)}^{k - 1}} - {{\left( {{p^{ - 1}}} \right)}^k}}  = 1 - {\left( {{p^{ - 1}}} \right)^N}\to 1$$ Recall a sum of positive terms converges if, and only if, it is bounded above.

Answer (score 2):

There are two steps to this problem. The first is to show the sum converges, and the second is to show that it converges to something in $[0,1]$.

To show it converges, I recommend you appeal to the definition of a convergent sum. That is, show that the partial sums form a Cauchy sequence. There are many ways of doing this, and I'll let you try working it on your own with that hint.

To show that it converges in $[0,1]$ (assuming it converges), consider the smallest-case and largest-case scenarios for values of $a_k$. That is: what values of $a_k$ give the smallest sum, and what give the biggest sum. Show that the lower bounds and upper bounds line in $[0,1]$, and you will be done.

Comment: *I recommend you appeal to the definition of a convergent sum. That is, show that the partial sums form a Cauchy sequence.* I think this will simply overcomplicate things.

Answer (score 1):

$$0 \le \sum_{i=1}^{\infty} \frac{a_i}{p^i} \le (p-1) \sum_{i=1}^{\infty} \frac{1}{p^i} = 1 $$